# Java Serial Communication PortInUseException

Tags: java, sms, gsm, modem, serial-communication

I have an SMS-based Java application using `CommV3` drivers for Serial communication to a GSM Modem. I have two separate codes, one for sending messages and one for receiving messages. Each code works perfectly when executed individually.

Now, when I want to integrate both these codes, I get a `PortInUseException`, which might be obvious. But, I am not sure where to start from.

Could I get pointers/ links/ tutorials where I could start resolving my issue. I do not have a clue where I should start from.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your code uses **one** SerialPort and not two. Then there is no problem reading or writing to this port.

```
SerialPort serialPort;
InputStream inStream;
OutputStream outStream;

serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(...);
serialPort.setFlowControlMode(...);
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(...);

inStream = serialPort.getInputStream ();
outStream = serialPort.getOutputStream ();
```

PS: [SMSLib](http://smslib.org) is an excellent Java library (ported to .NET Framework as well) which allows you to send/receive SMS messages via a compatible GSM modem or GSM phone. SMSLib also supports some bulk SMS operators. It is free and very stable.

Comment: I dont understand the parameters of the `portId.open(...)`. The API says appname and timeout... I guess I will look on these lines.

Comment: There are two parameters: The application's name and the timeout in milliseconds.  Example: `portId.open("MySMSApp", 5000);`

Comment: I have already used the Javax Comm library and so am hesitant on moving to SMSLib. However, if all else fails, I will take up your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I am sure that nothing will fail. Still SMSLib offers a lot of convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! I will definitely look at SMSLib too.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I understand I never closed the port for the other code to start using it... `serialPort.close()`

Comment: If you unite your code, you will only need to close() once, at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can separate out the listener code (which binds to a port) from 2 codes .
and dedicate to the appropriate code segment based on send / recieve.

Comment: That is exactly what I am not able to figure out... This is my first time programming with serial communication...